# How can I make sure my tests touch every line of my codebase?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a project about 10k lines big, and I'm trying to make sure everything is covered.

I know that there are much more sophisticated considerations, but as a baseline, I was wondering if there was a way to get `pytest` to tell me how many lines, as a percentage of number of lines in the codebase, it accessed.

For instance, it could notify me if in an if/else control structure, the tests only cover the True case, or if some function is never run at all.

This is certainly biased towards big lumbering unit tests instead of small precise ones, but I would still find it handy at this stage.

I imagine it is possible because tools such as the `line_profiler` can provide the information.

Comment: Did you search for coverage measurement tools?

Comment: I did, but not using the word 'coverage'. I guess that's where all the results were hiding.

Comment: Remember that coverage is a useful metric but does not *prove* your code is good, only that you have gone down all the paths. Your code might still be wrong if your tests are incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Coverage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) might be the tool you're looking for:

> Coverage.py measures code coverage, typically during test execution.
>   It uses the code analysis tools and tracing hooks provided in the
>   Python standard library to determine which lines are executable, and
>   which have been executed.

Coverage measures the lines you're covering and also help you identify pending lines. For example, in [coverage documentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/) you can see the kind of report it generates:

```
$ coverage report -m 
Name                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------
my_program                   20      4    80%   33-35, 39
my_other_module              56      6    89%   17-23
-------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                        76     10    87%
```

Comment: excellent

the specific command I ended up using was
`python2 -m coverage run --source mymod test_mymod.py && python2 -m coverage report`